# Create a Meteor User in Fixtures with specific ID?

Tags: meteor

I need to create a fixtures file and after a reset my `Meteor.user` needs to have a very specific ID because I need to preserve its relationships to other pieces of data, which use the user ID.

fixtures:

```
if ( Meteor.users.find().count() === 0 ) {
    Accounts.createUser({
        _id: "LHrhapueRmyJkajZ2", // This does not work, but I need it to be this.
        username: 'admin',
        email: 'admin@none.com',
        password: '123456',
        profile: {
            first_name: 'John',
            last_name: 'Doe',
            company: 'ABC',
        }
    });
};
```

UPDATE:

I figured out another way:

```
if ( Meteor.users.find().count() === 0 ) {
    var userId = Accounts.createUser({
        username: 'admin',
        email: 'none@none.com',
        password: '123456',
        profile: {
            first_name: 'John',
            last_name: 'Doe',
            company: 'ABC',
        }
    });
};
```

Then in the rest of my `fixtures` file I can use the `userId` variable to assign any "relationships" I want.

Comment: One way to do this is to establish an ordering to your fixtures, and fetch the existing documents as needed. For example if you had a posts fixture and posts need an owner, it could just fetch the any userId from the db (assuming the users fixture has already run).

Comment: Yup, that's sort of what I ended up doing in my update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have one global variable, when assigned one var without variable, this is global.

```
if ( Meteor.users.find().count() === 0 ) {
    userId = Accounts.createUser({
        username: 'admin',
        email: 'none@none.com',
        password: '123456',
        profile: {
            first_name: 'John',
            last_name: 'Doe',
            company: 'ABC',
        }
    });
};
```

On the other hand, you can have one `Session.set('user',value);`

```
if ( Meteor.users.find().count() === 0 ) {
    userId = Accounts.createUser({
        username: 'admin',
        email: 'none@none.com',
        password: '123456',
        profile: {
            first_name: 'John',
            last_name: 'Doe',
            company: 'ABC',
        }
    });
   Session.set('user',userId);  
 };
```

When you want to get the value:

```
 Session.get('user');
```

Comment: Something doesn't feel right here. Why would you want to create a global variable and store it in a reactive data source (session) for your userId in a fixtures file?

Comment: Sorry, Do you want fixture that test or fixture is a collection? Maybe , I understand that fixture was  for only test.

Answer (score 0):

if you want create one register with _id default you can do the of the following way

In your programn

> Collection.insert({_id:'id-default'});

If you want on Mongo Db, you open console and run Meteor, later open other console and execute in the folder the your project

> meteor mongo

For insert

> db.collection.insert({_id:'id-default'});